# Retrieve only the first row from each duplicate id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I want to retrieve **only the first row** from each duplicate `id` in a table.
The issue is that every other field except the id is unique, so that means I cannot "filter" the rows.

Here is my `scientist` table:

| id | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | albert | einstein |
| 1 | albert1 | einstein1 |
| 1 | albert2 | einstein2 |
| 1 | albert3 | einstein3 |
| 2 | isaac | newton |
| 2 | isaac1 | newton1 |
| 3 | marie | curie |
| 3 | marie1 | curie1 |
| 3 | marie2 | curie2 |

**Note:** *The `firstname` and the `lastname` are irrelevant I just want to extract the first row of each id.*

And below you can find my desired output:

| id | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | albert | einstein |
| 2 | isaac | newton |
| 3 | marie | curie |

I have tried to `GROUP BY id` but it is not working.

Also, I have tried to select the `scientist` table based on the `distinct ids` of the same table

```
SELECT * FROM scientist WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM scientist)
```

But then I realised that my logic was incorrect.

Comment: There is no way of establishing first from your data so not possible..

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for the answer. Does That mean that I need to add extra data to distinguish the first row of each id?

Comment: Yes, an auto_increment column and/or an updated/created date column.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you I suppose I will go with the date_created column solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it here [enter link description here](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yqkfbucm)

```
 select id,firtname,lastname
        from(    
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY scientist.id) c
            from scientist) t
        Where c = 1
```